# Is it possible to get specific information about how a file is compressed?

Tags: software-rec, compression

File compression works on the basic idea of assigning commonly recurring chains of strings to a common index of a table where the full string is stored.

For example:

```
Input file: foo bar bash baz foo foo bash foo baz baz foo baz foo bar
Output file: foo ,bar ,bash ,baz |01230020330301
```

I understand that this is a trivial example and actual file structures and algorithms are much more complex, but my question is, are there any existing compression utilities that provide options for viewing this sort meta-data in some way given a specific archive? Possibly for educational purposes?

Comment: I'm not sure this is always possible. From what I understand, in a file compressed using an [adaptive Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Huffman_coding), the “metadata” depends on the data itself, and the table you describe actually evolves during the extraction of the file.

Comment: I wonder if possibly there is a compression utility that uses a simpler algorithm useable for education purposes.

Comment: @CoryKlein Grab sources of some compression utility (`gzip`, `xz`...), add debug code, that will print the dictionary and run it on a simple file you prepare. That's one of the original reasons behind GPL - being able to study and modify the code that is running on your system. :)